# How is make this html table?

Tags: html

I must create this table, but colspan and rowspan make my brain crazy. Please help.

Jsfiddle blank for experiments, - http://jsfiddle.net/3pbuT/2/
[image]

Comment: You might want to take a look at some basic websites like http://www.w3schools.com/html/ or (if you can read german) http://de.selfhtml.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly straight-forward..... Your'e confusion is the number of rows you had. There are only 2 rows in that table.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3pbuT/3/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ... if you have dreamweaver tool you can do this very easily....

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is Dreamweaver, but it doesn't take much to deal with colspan and rowspan, I just did this with very little thinking, and I used jsfiddle just to make sure it was correct.

Enjoy.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2"></td>
<td rowspan="2"></td>
<td colspan="4"></td>
<td rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">город 1</th>
            <th rowspan="2">город 2</th>
            <th colspan="4">город 3</th>
            <th rowspan="2">город 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>город 5</th>
            <th>город 6</th>
            <th>город 7</th>
            <th>город 8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3pbuT/9/

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">one</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Two</td>
            <td colspan="4">Im big!</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Last</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">one</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Two</td>
            <td>Part 1</td>
            <td>Part 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go..

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2"></td>
  <td rowspan="2"></td>
  <td colspan="4"></td>
  <td rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

colspan combines columns, rowspan combines rows. So you look at how many rows are there at maximum and how many columns there at maximum.

In your case you have 7 columns at maximum and 2 rows at maximum:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
        <td>m</td>
        <td>n</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then you combine columns / rows:

```
<table border="1" style="padding:5px;border-spacing:10px">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">a (former a)</td>
        <td rowspan="2">b (former b)</td>
        <td colspan="4">c (former c)</td>
        <td rowspan="2">d (former g)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type='text/css'>
      table {
        border-spacing:0;
      }

      td {
        border:1px solid grey;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan='2'>1 col, 2 rows</td>
        <td rowspan='2'>1 col, 2 rows</td>
        <td colspan='4'>4 col, 1 row</td>
        <td rowspan='2'>1 col, 2 rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1 col, 1 row</td>
        <td>1 col, 1 row</td>
        <td>1 col, 1 row</td>
        <td>1 col, 1 row</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

*EDIT - I'd recommend against WYSIWYG editors, because you won't learn how to do it yourself.  Learning will make a few headaches, sure, but then you KNOW.  Give a man a fish...*